# Replace a key in one dictionary with the value of the key from another dictionary in Python

Tags: python

I have 2 dictionaries in python

```
dict1={'_Switch1': {'portB': '20', 'portA': '10'}, '_Switch2': {'portB': '200', 'portA': '100'}}

dict2={'_Switch1': {'portB': 'eth1/2', 'portA': 'eth1/1'}, '_Switch2': {'portB': 'eth2/2', 'portA': 'eth2/1'}}
```

I am looking for a a simple way how i can map the value of key in dict2 to dict1.

the resultant dictionary should look something like this

```
dict3={'_Switch1': {'eth1/2': '20', 'eth1/1: '10'}, '_Switch2': {'eth2/2': '200', 'eth2/1': '100'}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use nested dict comprehension:

```
>>> dict1={'_Switch1': {'portB': '20', 'portA': '10'}, '_Switch2': {'portB': '200', 'portA': '100'}}
>>> dict2={'_Switch1': {'portB': 'eth1/2', 'portA': 'eth1/1'}, '_Switch2': {'portB': 'eth2/2', 'portA': 'eth2/1'}}
>>> {k: {dict2[k][k2]: dict1[k][k2] for k2 in dict1[k]} for k in dict1}
{'_Switch1': {'eth1/1': '10', 'eth1/2': '20'}, '_Switch2': {'eth2/2': '200', 'eth2/1': '100'}}
```

In above `for k in dict1` iterates over the keys in `dict1`. Then for each key another dict comprehension is used where the keys in nested dict are iterated over: `for k2 in dict1[k]`.

For each key in nested dicts key value pair `dict2[k][k2]: dict[k][k2]` is added to resulting subdictionary. Finally the outer key and generated subdictionary are added to the result.

Answer (score 0):

I think one way of accomplishing this is simply writing nested loops for one dictionary. (Of course you can use list comprehension as well, but I am using nested loops to make it easy to read)

```
    dict1={'_Switch1': {'portB': '20', 'portA': '10'}, '_Switch2': {'portB': '200', 'portA': '100'}}

    dict2={'_Switch1': {'portB': 'eth1/2', 'portA': 'eth1/1'}, '_Switch2': {'portB': 'eth2/2', 'portA': 'eth2/1'}}

    #This will be the new dictionary
    dict3 = {}

    for key in dict1:
        tmpdict = {}
        for key_child, item in dict1[key].iteritems():
            tmpdict[dict2[key][key_child]] = item
        dict3[key] = tmpdict
```